# Node mysql cannot get a response on a query

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I have a trouble when i pass a function inside my query. When i run my code without the function just work without any problem. With it on postman is stuck on "Sending request"

Example:

```
save() {
    return db.query(
      {
        sql: "INSERT INTO contenido (titulo, extencion_archivo, fecha_publicacion) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
        values: [this.titulo, this.extension, this.fecha]
      }, function(err, res, fields) {
        //More code
      }
    );
  }
```

Following code work without any problem:

```
  save() {
    return db.query(
      {
        sql: "INSERT INTO contenido (titulo, extencion_archivo, fecha_publicacion) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
        values: [this.titulo, this.extension, this.fecha]
      }
    );
  }
```

How i call save method:

```
exports.addVideo = (req, res, next) => {
  const titulo = req.body.titulo;
  const extension = req.file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
  const fecha = new Date();
  const videoUrl = req.file.filename;
  const video = new Videos(null, titulo, extension, fecha, videoUrl);
  video.save().then(() => {
    res.json('sending')
  })

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using .then on function save() which is not promise returning function. I think that may be the reason for you not getting any response for your postman request.

Try running this code :

```
function save() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.query(
            {
                sql: "INSERT INTO contenido (titulo, extencion_archivo, fecha_publicacion) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",
                values: [this.titulo, this.extension, this.fecha]
            }, function (err, res, fields) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error Occurred :", err);
                    reject();
                }
                console.log("Successfully Sent :", res);
                resolve();
            }
        );
    })
}
```

and

```
exports.addVideo = (req, res, next) => {
    const titulo = req.body.titulo;
    const extension = req.file.mimetype.split("/")[1];
    const fecha = new Date();
    const videoUrl = req.file.filename;
    const video = new Videos(null, titulo, extension, fecha, videoUrl);
    video.save().then(() => {
        res.json('sending')
    }).catch(() =>{
        res.json('Error Occurred')
    })

};
```

Please try this if it works well and good else let me know I will try to help you around this.